# How to create my own C I/O functions which are faster than the standard printf and scanf?

Tags: c

I have found many geeky coders who are creating their own functions for input and output in C in order to reduce their runtime. But I am facing a very hard time in understanding their code.

So could you please explain me how to create such fast IO functions in simple and plain English ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot write fast IO functions in simple and plain English.  You will need to use a programming language.

Comment: see write(2) and read(2)

Comment: How can we explain how they did it without knowing what they've done?  printf/scanf are high level functions with a great deal of functionality, higher performance can always be achieved using the simpler lower-level functions in which they are implemented - so long as you don't want the same functionality. But even then if you want I/O for a specific hardware interface, you could in principle bypass even the OS and device driver layer and probably get optimum performance.  But who knows what your intended interface is?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Ok, if not simple and plain English, then a programming language would be helpful. Please explain such trick with an example. Thnaks!

Comment: @user3606997 Please explain a situation with an example where printf is "Slow" and then maybe, someone can suggest a "faster" way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single threaded code, you can use `getchar_unlocked()` and `putchar_unlocked()` functions in `stdio.h` library to get I/O fast. Here is a simple example of how you can use this functions,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
    char c = getchar_unlocked( );
    printf( "%c" , c );
    return 0;
}
```

But do remember that it is *not thread safe*. So use it with precautions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking for. Thanks!

Comment: Do note that these POSIX functions are not part of the C Standard Library.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis ya, I know that but I guessed this is what she actually referred.

Answer (score 3):

In order to squeeze the most performance out of console I/O on Windows, you'll need to use the [Windows system calls for managing the console.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) On Linux, the standard C functions `read` and `write` will be the most performant.

Now, if you want to use format strings, you will have to create a format parser and evaluator. If you have a variety of functions like `print_int(int)`, `print_string(const char*)` that you call directly in your code, you can see some small performance improvements on Linux. On Windows, you can see some huge improvements if you use the console buffer management system calls.

For the most part though, stdarg processing is going to eat up most of the processing time for the `printf` family, and an even larger chunk of processing time is going to be consumed by the actual act of writing out to the console buffer. If you really need to spew megabytes worth of `printf`s a second, route it to a file. The `printf` operation will be practically free if you do that, and the disk I/O will be the bottleneck at that point.